# Video doesn't show up in render

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I have never tried to do this so I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. It shows in the preview window but not in the final animation.

[image: Viewport Result.]

[image: Render Result.]

Comment: It could be many things... If you don't tell us how you are composing the image in the background. It's that a plane? Or you use the compositor? Or... Please provide a blend file as an example http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and be sure you have checked basic things like the render visibility button in the outline or the ray visibility in the object panel

Comment: It is not a plane, and I am not using the compositor.... Maybe that is my problem?

<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1108" /> (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1108/)

Comment: The blend file that you uploaded has no background.

Comment: Yes it does... I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images used as background in the 3D viewport are used for reference only and will not render unless you choose to combine them with the scene using the compositor.

Open a Node Editor window. Add a movie clip node and select your video clip. Set the movie clip to be used as the background input on an Alpha Over node and plug the render layers as foreground.

For Blender Render the setup is like this:

[image]
(click on the image to enlarge)

To Render using cycles this is the node setup:
[image]

Make sure that the compostitng box is checked:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! :)