# How Do You Re-render a previously rendered animation after using the Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

Hi I have run into this problem before and desperately tried to find the answer again but couldn't.

I rendered a scene, then edited in the video sequence editor, then went back to re render the animation and when I hit the render animation button it just produces blank black renders.

I am attaching a file.

[image]

Comment: When I render your scene, it isn't blank. I can see your animation and the frames get written correctly.

Comment: If you have any strips on the VSE those take precedence over the 3D scene. In the post processing section you can uncheck the *sequencer*  box and the scene should render normally

Comment: @cegaton could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: I can't do that from my phone

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5285/1853

Comment: @cegaton if you are referring to the sequencer and compositing checkboxes under post processing section of the render tab I have both of them uncheck and when I hit the render animation button it still produces blannk black renders. Could there be some cache to clear or something?

Comment: See if any of the reasons for blank rendering applies in this case: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53633/1853

Comment: @cegaton yes thank you for the link. Im stumped because I unchecked both those boxes and made sure there is nothing in the VSE

Comment: @cegaton It appears that I have somehow accidentally copied the gun in my scene to every single layer. Could this be the cause. I am unable to remove it from one layer without deleting it from all the layers

Comment: @Leander did you alter any of the settings to get the correct non blank render? I have followed all of the trouble shooting steps provided by cegaton and it still produces blank black renders. Im really not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: So I found the answer. It wasnt showing up because I was trying to use an imported video that wasnt connected in the compositor and I had left background transparent on under the film section of render. After trying to render a part of the video further down I saw objects in the render. To fix this you have to connect it to the render like shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48941/video-doesnt-show-up-in-render

Comment: Post an answer with your solution then. In your uploaded file, I couldn't find any refernences to a video, thats why I didn't expect anything to be rendern during the first few frames. EDIT : beat me

Answer (score 3):

So I found the answer. It wasnt showing up because I was trying to use an imported video that wasnt connected in the compositor and I had left background transparent on under the film section of render. After trying to render a part of the video further down I saw objects in the render. To fix this you have to connect it to the render like shown at [Video doesn't show up in render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48941/).

After it is connected the background video will show up in the render